# Why is html page not displaying hindi fonts?

Tags: html, css

I want to write a para in Hindi language. And for that, I have copied and pasted a link of mukta-fonts in html page from google fonts site. Also, I have copied and pasted the font family in css. Still, the page is not showing Hindi fonts. Could you please help me?

```css
p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title> Hindi Test </title>
</head>

<body>
  <p lang="hi">
    rqe dSls gksA esjk uke r:.k gSA D;k dj jgs gks
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML and you are inconsistent in its usage on top of that.

Comment: I have made corrections suggested by you, but the problem is still there. Could you please help me further?

Answer (score 1):

adding `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` in header worked for me

Comment: Almost 5 hours wasted, finally it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just wrote twice `font-family`.

You used `font-family: font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;` instead of `font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;`.

```css
p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.special {
  font-family: 'Mukta', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<p class="special">
  This is Mukta FONT
</p>
<p>
  This is default FONT
</p>
```

Comment: I have made the corrections suggested by you, but the problems is still there. Could you please help me further?

Comment: @TarunRathore can you see that it's working in the snippet?

Comment: Sorry, as I can see, it's not working. I have run it on the snippet.

Comment: @TarunRathore Iv'e edited my answer. Can you see that the font is different ?

Comment: Thanks. I have got you, but the problem is I need the fonts in Hindi language.

Comment: @TarunRathore so maybe Hindi isn't supported by the font you imported

Answer (score -1):

How about use @font-face ?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Mukta';
}
```

I think there is no error in your code.

It is good way to print Mukta font to download font file instead of webfont.

Comment: he is importing the `@font-face` from a url so it's not the problem